# Diffusion equation with time dependent coefficients in boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am trying to solve heat diffusion equation:
$$\frac{\partial^{2} T}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{g(t)}{k}=\frac{1}{α}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$
With initial condition
$$T(x,t=0)=T_0$$
Boundary conditions:
At $x=0$

$$-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}+h_1(t)T=q(t)$$

At $x=L$

$$-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}+h_2(t)T=0$$

I cannot use separation of variables to solve this because of the time dependent coefficients.
Can anyone suggest how to approach this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $\dfrac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{g(t)}{k} = \dfrac{1}{\alpha}\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ in your first equation?  Otherwise, it's an ODE, not really what is usually called a heat equation.  Cheers!

Comment: No $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ term?

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is with a Laplace transform in $t$, which will leave you with a BVP in $x$, which will give you a solution $\hat{T}(x,s)$. Inverting the Laplace Transform will then give you your solution

Comment: Sorry about the typo in the pde. I cannot use Laplace transform because h1(t) and h2(t) are random functions.